# Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type with CheckboxSelectMultiple

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm using the django form wizard and getting this error when I use any multiple selection. I don't know why I'm getting it but I think it's because I'm passing multiple datas because it does work with a unique selection (like radioselect).

```
Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type
```

Here is the code : **forms.py**

```
class CustomChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<div><p class="companyname" style="%s">My company</p></div>' % (obj.font_css))

class ContactForm1(forms.ModelForm):
    choice_box = CustomChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=ImageCheckView.objects.all(), empty_label=None)

    class Meta:
        model = ImageCheckView
        fields = ['title', 'choice_box']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choice_box'].empty_label = None
```

**views.py**

```
class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(ContactWizard, self).get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)
        if self.steps.current == '0':
            context.update({'datas': ImageCheckView.objects.all()})
        return context

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        form_data = process_form_data(form_list)
        context = {'form_data': form_data}
        return render_to_response('done.html', context)


def process_form_data(form_list):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
    return form_data
```

Any suggestion to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue by replacing

```
class CustomChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
```

by

```
class CustomChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
```

Now multiple checkbox field is passed through steps and work fine on the form wizard.